# Trying to highlight active menu item

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is my HTML that shows the sidebar menu:

```
    <div class="sidebar">
      <a class="active" href="<website>/humrec.php">HR Homepage</a>
      <a href="<website>/hrbenefits.php">Benefits Information</a>
      <a href="#contact">Scheduling</a>
      <a href="#about">Links</a>
    </div>
```

Here is the jQuery code I have, still not working though:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".sidebar a").click(function ( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".sidebar a.active").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class  
            $("a", this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab  

            // $(activeTab).show(); //Fade in the active content  
        });
    });
```

Comment: `$("a", this)` looking for anchors inside of the anchor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You logic is almost correct, however the issue is `$("a", this)`. That selector is looking for an `a` element within `this`. The problem is that `this` is the `a` which was just clicked, so you're looking for an `a` within an `a`, which doesn't match the HTML structure you've got.

To fix the problem you just need to use `$(this)` to reference the `a` which was clicked:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".sidebar a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".sidebar a.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
  <a class="active" href="<website>/humrec.php">HR Homepage</a>
  <a href="<website>/hrbenefits.php">Benefits Information</a>
  <a href="#contact">Scheduling</a>
  <a href="#about">Links</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, but now my url is staying the same when switching menu items.

Comment: That's because you've used `preventDefault()` which stops the page redirection. If you want to highlight the current page link when changing page you need to do this in a completely different way. You would need to recognise the new page as it loads and then put the class on the matching link within the JS of that page, not the one on which the link was clicked.

Comment: Ah okay I see.  Thank you.